# Proper usage of NSViewController representedObject

Tags: cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I have a `NSViewController` managing a `NSTableView` and noticed that `NSViewController` has a `representedObject` property, however it isn't an IBOutlet and I'm not able to bound the `dataSource` of `NSTableView` to the `representedObject` property of `NSViewController` in interface builder. How is representedObject property suppose to be used? Are there any examples of proper usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `representedObject` property should be set to an object that lives outside of the nib, such as the document, another model-controller, or a model object. Things in the nib should get the data from the VC or the VC's `representedObject`.

Comment: Hmm, what's the best way to get a reference to the ViewController from objects initialized by the nib? (in other words, how do you get to file's owner from inside code?

Comment: @Tony: Give them a reference to it, either by connecting an outlet or setting up a binding.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but I thought I'd add to it as I did quite a bit of research into representedObject. Hope this helps!

`representedObject` is a reference to some `AnyObject` (`NSObject`) that the view should represent.

It's NOT a copy of the object, but rather a reference to it (both in Swift and Objective-C)

Ideally speaking, if the view in question is a page out a "contacts app". This page `represents a contact` then the representedObject *should* be set to `fooContact` by the object that instantiated it. `fooContact` being a reference to an instance of the contact in question.

It doesn't have to be set by the instantiating class, but personally I find it a cleaner approach to things.

I generally avoid trying to override the default getters/setters of the representedbject and reference it by another var in the class i.e.

```
weak var document: Document{
    if let docRef = self.representedObject as Document {
        return docRef
    }
    return nil
}
```

maintaining the weak reference will avoid reference cycles.

Comment: You cannot use weak ref like that, you cannot return nil either. All your code can be deducted to returning representedObject casted to Document?     weak var document: Document? {
        return representedObject as? Document
    }

Comment: I was going to say the same thing.  It should be a guard-let with a preconditionFailure (or simply a fatalError).  If it was a case where you want to return an optional, then a simple `return self.representedObject as? Document` would suffice, no if-let or guard-let needed.